# Escape Unicode in Android OnTextChanged event :Like "price:10rs" to "\u0070\u0072\u0069\u0063\u0065\u003A\u0031\u0030\u0072\u0073"

Tags: android, unicode-escapes

How can I escape any Unicode in android OnTextChanged event?? Like "price" to "`\u0070\u0072\u0069\u0063\u0065`".  I tried it but I cant find any solution. This is my textwatcher

```
  price.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           }

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
             int count, int after) {
           }

           @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
             int before, int count) {

          MainActivity.this.priceshow(s);

           }
          });
```

and this is my CharSequence

```
 private String priceshow (CharSequence s) {
            String priceshowstring= "";
            priceshowstring = s.toString().replace("","");
            System.out.println(priceshowstring);
            return priceshowstring;
            }
```

Comment: Why would you need to encode ASCII characters ?

Comment: @Abkarino,  i create new app.bet when i add any symbol or some indian language .then i showing only boxex

Comment: The example is misleading as you are only using ASCII text in the example. Can you please tell me the source of the text you use?
Is it hardcoded or from external source ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert character to its Unicode representation you can use

```
String.format("\\u%04x", (int) character);
```

Use StringBuilder to convert whole CharSequence

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0, length = charSequence.length(); i < length; i++) {
    builder.append(String.format("\\u%04x", (int) charSequence.charAt(i)));
}
String result = builder.toString();
```